# List wcf service addresses when no address or baseaddress is specified in the web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

How do I get all the wcf 4.0 service addresses from each project in the Visual Studio solution when the services section endpoints in the web configs don’t specify an address or baseaddress? I intend to write the list of service addresses out to an aspx page. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's an example of one of the service sections in the web config.

```
<services>
<service name="ABC.Enterprise.Flight.FlightService">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="ICRMManagement"                contract="ABC.Enterprise.Flight.IFlightService"/>
    <endpoint address="MexBasic" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexBasic" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Comment: You can't - if you host this service in IIS, it's the IIS **virtual directory** (plus the name of the `*.svc` file) that defines the service address. So it's really dependent on where your service is hosted, and you don't have any "knowledge" of that if you read the `web.config` from the "outside"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback marc_s. We'll probably end up adding the addresses to the endpoints and use variable replace during deployment to specify the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WCF Discovery to find endpoints at runtime...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx